# Why i am getting undefined local variable or method `role' in cucumber test cases

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise, cancan, rolify

`following error i am getting`

```
   And I am exists as a parent      # features/step_definitions/kid_steps.rb:106
   undefined local variable or method `role' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0xc4722f8> (NameError)
  ./features/step_definitions/event_steps.rb:10:in `create_visitor'
  ./features/step_definitions/event_steps.rb:14:in `create_user'
  ./features/step_definitions/kid_steps.rb:107:in `/^I am exists as a parent$/'
  features/manage_kids.feature:11:in `And I am exists as a parent'
```

user factories

```
          FactoryGirl.define do

           factory :user do
             email "user@example.com"
             password "test123"
             password_confirmation "test123"
          end
          factory :role do
             id "1"
             name "admin"

             id "2" 
             name "parent"

             id "3" 
             name "gifter"
          end
       end </code>
```

`user.rb`

```
    def role?(role)
       return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s)
    end
```

`ability.rb`

```
   class Ability
     include CanCan::Ability

     def initialize(user)

      user ||= User.new #user

        entities = [Kid, Customer, Event, Contact]

         # check if user is 'admin' grant all permissions
       if user.role? :admin
        can :manage, :all
      else
       can :manage, entities
      end

    end
  end
```

#event_steps.rb

```
       def create_visitor

             @visitor ||= { :email => "user@example.com",
             :password => "test123", 
             :password_confirmation => "test123", 
             :role => Role.find_by_name(role.to_s)}
      end
```

I have tried so much to resolve problem by my own along with i have googled also but i couldn't able to solve it,& i am new to ruby on rails as well as cucumber also.Please guide me if i am wrong ,your help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the stacktrace carefully:

```
   And I am exists as a parent      # features/step_definitions/kid_steps.rb:106
   undefined local variable or method `role' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0xc4722f8> (NameError)
  ./features/step_definitions/event_steps.rb:10:in `create_visitor'
  ./features/step_definitions/event_steps.rb:14:in `create_user'
  ./features/step_definitions/kid_steps.rb:107:in `/^I am exists as a parent$/'
  features/manage_kids.feature:11:in `And I am exists as a parent'
```

you will find the error message `undefined local variable or method 'role'` and the location of the source code that is raising the error `./features/step_definitions/event_steps.rb:10` even with the method that is executed `create_visitor`.

When looking at the source that you posted:

```
def create_visitor
  @visitor ||= { :email => "user@example.com",
    :password => "test123", 
    :password_confirmation => "test123", 
    :role => Role.find_by_name(role.to_s)} # i assume that this is line 10!
end
```

you can see that you are calling `role`. From the code that you post, there is no point where `role` is defined. There has to be a variable or a method with that name. Maybe it's just a typo and you mean an instance variable `@role`.

there is nothing more that we can help you, it's all in your code...

Comment: thanks phoet for very aggressive answer but that helped me, i have found the problem and where i was doing mistake.Actually in place of role their should be :role_ids needed and my issue solved.